# Cannot see video playing in website in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video

I am trying to embed two .mp4 videos in my asp.net mvc application.

I have created a folder called as Content in my project directory and put both the videos there.

I am trying to embed the videos as follows:

```
<video src="~/Content/somevideo.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" style="width:100%" muted="muted" loop="loop"></video>
```

The problem is one of the video plays, while the other video doesn't display anything at all.

It's something like this - [image]

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your `src` attribute, have you used Razor syntax in your view?

Comment: yes i do. I even tried uploading this to Azure storage and pointing a url from there. But i still get the same problem. Moreover the other video displays correctly.

Comment: Try a tool called **mediaInfo**... what _profile_ type does it say for both working & non-working videos? Make sure both videos have h264 video codec inside those mp4 files. Otherwise put a link to the problematic 26-sec video so we test it ourselves...

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<html>
<video id="videoclip"  title="Video title"  width="800" height="600"  controls autoplay>
<source  class="active" id="mp4video1" src="../Content/QMSVideo/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">      
 <source id="mp4video2" src="../Content/QMSVideo/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source id="mp4video3" src="../Content/QMSVideo/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source id="mp4video4" src="../Content/QMSVideo/video4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source id="mp4video5" src="../Content/QMSVideo/video5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source id="mp4video6" src="../Content/QMSVideo/video6.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
<html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myvid = document.getElementById('videoclip');
    for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
        debugger;
    myvid.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
        // get the active source and the next video source.
        // I set it so if there's no next, it loops to the first one

        var activesource = document.querySelector("#videoclip source.active");

        var nextsource = document.querySelector("#videoclip source.active + source") || document.querySelector("#videoclip source:first-child");
        // deactivate current source, and activate next one
        activesource.className = "";
        nextsource.className = "active";
        // update the video source and play
        myvid.src = nextsource.src;
        myvid.play();
    });
        }

</script>
```

This will help you to play more than 2 videos from Project folder videos. This is work for me. try it.